# Is it possible to have multiple instances of a Spring security OAuth2-based service behind a Proxy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, multiple-instances

We intend to develop an authorization/authentication service based on Spring Security OAuth2 implementation. One of the thing we are concerned about is the ability to scale the service if needed : does anyone know or had a good experience **having multiple instances** of a Spring Security OAuth2 service behind an HAProxy or any other frontal proxy for example ?
Any issues related to concurrency ?